# Find function and if elseif to Avoid Duplicates from User Form input

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, userform

I am really new to VBA and have been struggling with the code for a userform that needs to check the input values before adding the table to avoid duplicates and provide directions in a message box.

When the user clicks the "transfer" command button, I would like the code to first look at WONumber that the user is trying to input see if is already on the table. If the WONumber is not on the table, a msgbox appears telling the user the WONumber does not exist.

If the WONumber is on the table, I want the code to then look at SubName for all the cases where the WONumber matches their input and see if the SubName they are trying to input already exists on the table with the associated WONumber. If the SubName is already on the table with the WONumber, a msgbox appears letting the user know that the SubName is already on the WONumber.  If the SubName is on the table but not with the same user input WONumber, the SubName with the associated WONumber is added to the table.  Essentially, the WONumber is unique to the table and the SubName is unique to the WONumber but not unique to the table. (The user SHOULD be able add SubName = "Smith" with WONumber = "5" and SubName = "Smith" with WONumber = "500" but SHOULD NOT be able to add SubName = "Smith" with WONumber = "5" twice.)

I've tried multiple combinations of If Not Nothing since I've read that sometimes it's easier to work from that direction.

I have very little experience with VBA in general so I don't know if the .Find returns a value or a location so the ElseIf conditions I have written may not make sense at all since the code might be finding a location and I am asking it to match text.

I've tried FoundWO.Value = PsblWOMatch.Value and FoundSub.Value = FoundSubName.Value as the Elseif conditions as well as .text.

I'm not sure about the dim FoundWO as Range, FoundSub as Range since that seems to imply that FoundWO would be set of values and to equate a set of numbers with one PsblWOMatch really doesn't make sense.

I've also found a few YouTube videos about the specific error code 91 having to do with my code not including dim ws as worksheet that being the issue but when I have tried to correct it to match the example I get the same error code just on a different line.

```
Private Sub cmdTransfer_Click()

    Dim FoundWO As Range
    Dim PsblWOMatch As String
    PsblWOMatch = txtWONumber.Text

    Dim FoundSub As Range
    Dim PsblSubMatch As String
    PsblSubMatch = txtSubName.Text

    Dim eRow As Long
    eRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    Set FoundWO = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableWO").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Find(What:=PsblWOMatch, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set FoundSub = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableWO").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Find(What:=PsblSubMatch, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)

    'If Condition 1 then
    If FoundWO Is Nothing Then
        'Code to execute
        MsgBox "Work Order does not exist. Please add Work Order before adding subcontractors."

    'If Condition 2 then
    ElseIf FoundWO = PsblWOMatch And FoundSub = PsblSubMatch Then
        'Code to execute
        MsgBox "SubContractor has already been added to Work Order."

    Else
        'Code to execute
        Cells(eRow, 1).Value = txtWONumber.Text
        Cells(eRow, 2).Value = ""
        Cells(eRow, 3).Value = txtSubName.Text
        Cells(eRow, 4).Value = txtsubLocation.Text

    End If

    txtWONumber.Text = ""
    txtSubName.Text = ""
    txtsubLocation = ""
    txtWONumber.SetFocus

End Sub
```

I've been able to get the msgbox to appear telling the user that the WONumber does not exist.  And I have been able to add a SubName when the WONumber does exist.  But I am getting Run time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. The debug highlight is on the ElseIf line.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of observations:
First, the .find property returns a Range object. In the ElseIf statement, you're comparing it to a string variable.

Try this if you want to compare the value of a range object to a string:
ElseIf FoundWO.value = PsblWOMatch And FoundSub.value = PsblSubMatch

Next, although you test for the existence of FoundWO, you never test for the existence of FoundSub. You will get an Object Variable Not Set error if the subcontractor is not found. Test for this the same way you tested for FoundWO before trying to use this object.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you. I thought the range/string comparison was some of it. But hadn’t been able to reason through it and have it make sense in my head.

Comment: Follow up question. To handle the test for existence of the SubName I want to make sure I’m only looking at the range where the WONumber matches the user input WONumber and all the associated SubNames on that WONumber. Am I correct in thinking that I will need to define a new range that is the intersection of the WONumber.value = user input and SubName and compare the user input SubName to the new range? There will be cases in which the SubName does exist but is not associated with the same WONumber.

Comment: First, test for the existence of the object. Until you know the the range was found, you shouldn't try to compare it to anything.

Creating another range object shouldn't be necessary. The comparisons can be handled by nesting "If..Then..Else" statements.

Comment: I think you're looking for something like:
If FoundWO Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "Work Order does not exist. Please add Work Order before adding subcontractors."
Else
  If FoundSub Is Nothing Then
    Cells(eRow, 1).Value = txtWONumber.Text
    Cells(eRow, 2).Value = ""
    Cells(eRow, 3).Value = txtSubName.Text
    Cells(eRow, 4).Value = txtsubLocation.Text
  Else
    MsgBox "SubContractor has already been added to Work Order."
  End If
End if

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
If FoundWO Is Nothing Then 'need to add a work order first
  MsgBox "Work Order does not exist. Please add Work Order before adding subcontractors."
Else
  If FoundSub Is Nothing Then 'No subcontractor found. OK to add.
    Cells(eRow, 1).Value = txtWONumber.Text
    Cells(eRow, 2).Value = ""
    Cells(eRow, 3).Value = txtSubName.Text
    Cells(eRow, 4).Value = txtsubLocation.Text
  Else
    MsgBox "SubContractor has already been added to Work Order." 'Someone already added the subcontractor
  End If
End if
```

Comment: I really appreciate this feedback.  I tried using the If FoundSub is Nothing Ok to add route yesterday after your response and I don't get the error but it allows the duplicate FoundSub to added to the WONumber.

Comment: I explored the idea of creating a collection based on adding the WONumber to the collection and then looking at the SubName in the collection as well.  I'm still learning VBA so I'm not sure that the Collection is needed or if an intersection would be more streamlined.  Like I said, I'm really appreciative of the feedback.  The insights you have already provided have been super helpful.

Comment: The Code I posted will only add FoundSub if it doesn't currently exist in the range you're searching. If you haven't already, give it a try.

Comment: When working with values, you also need to ensure spelling is exactly the same. The word "duplicate" is deceptively simple when matching strings.